# Why does one third belong to the Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

We know that all numbers that belong to the Cantor set have a ternary representation with only 0's and 2's but, for example, $\frac{1}{3}=(0.1)_3$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ belong to the Cantor set. I don't understand and I have already read tons of sources. Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

Comment: The answers below are, of course correct.  Perhaps another way to go is to realize that we only delete open intervals in the usual iterated construction.  So, first we delete $(1/3,2/3)$ which leaves 1/3 in the set and it never gets subsequently deleted.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$(0.1)_3 = (0.0222\ldots)_3$, just as $0.1 = 0.0999\ldots$ in base $10$.

Comment: lol you win by 4 seconds. =)

Comment: @user21820 Apparently you typed too many $2$s :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yea.. all because I wanted to make an infinitesimal attempt to emphasize the infinite ternary expansion.

Answer (score 20):

$0.02222222222222222222..._3 = 0.1_3$

Comment: Either you wrote too many $2$s or infinitely too few $2$s. I can't decide.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Hahaha.. I held down the `2` on my keyboard for about one second.

Comment: @columbus8myhw No, it's not too many. The notation means there is 18 twos, and then a two infinitely repeating. That's perfectly true (despite other notations, like $0.022222222\dots_3$ or $0.0222\dots_3$ or $0.022\dots_3$, which result in the same meaning).

Comment: @CiaPan: Haha *columbus8myhw* was joking..

Comment: @user21820 About the only ways to mess it up would have been things like $0.0222...2_3$ or $0.0\bar{2}2_3$

Comment: @Brian Another way would be `7`.

Comment: Blast you, @Paulpro, and your paradigm-breaking cleverness!

Comment: @Paulpro: Is your comment supposed to be easily understood?

Comment: More elegant is perhaps `0.0\dot{2}`, which yields $0.0\dot{2}$.

Comment: @PJTraill: I'm aware of that, though I usually use `\overline`. I purposely wrote a long string of twos just for fun.

Comment: Fair enough; I am still fairly new to MathJax, so it took me a little while to find. I suppose $0.0\overline{2}2$ is a sequence defined on $\omega+1$ ;) Is $\overline{2}$ more common than $\dot{2}$ in your neck of the woods? Could that be another question coming on?

Comment: @PJTraill: Well it was never in the school syllabus so the notation I picked up comes from all kinds of sources. Anyway, both overline and dots are given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal so there should not be any question about it.

Comment: No question; that’s clear.

Answer (score 2):

Any endpoint of removed intervals belongs to Cantor set.